# Consequences of revoking certificates due to lost private keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

We lost private keychain (formatted that machine) and cannot create new build to publish update to our live app.

Can I now safely delete certificate belonging to this app?

Anyway, what is the worst thing that can happen when I delete certificate belonging to some application?

Comment: Why don't you have a backup of your keychain or certificates?

Comment: @rmaddy We have for 99.99% of them, and the only one got formatted :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst thing that can happen if you delete a certificate for an app is that you will need to create a new certificate and then update all of your provisioning profiles to use the new certificate. All of this will needed to be done before you can install the app on another device or submit the app to Apple.

It will have no affect on any apps you have in the store or on any existing devices.

Answer (score 1):

You may safely revoke your old certificate and create a new one. Certificates are only required for submissions, and all submissions don't need the same cert. Revoking the certificate will not affect your app in the store in any way.

Probably worthy to note that revoking an APS certificate will temporarily disable your push notifications, until you create a new one.